# Is there a way to search for events with a equals-sign in Google Calendar?

Tags: google, google-calendar

I have events called "=====" (5 equals sign) in Google Calendar. I use it to mark stuff that I want to remember.

But I can't search through these events. If I use the Search function in Google Calendar, I think `=` is treated as a special thing and well basically, it fails to search for those events called "=====".

Is there a way to search for events with a equals-sign in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to use a non-word description - if you don't want to reveal to others viewing the calendar what it actually is, you could still use something vague/generic like "rem" or "xxxxx" which would both be searchable.

However, if you really don't want that, whilst searching for equals doesn't seem to work, what you can do is use underscore instead.

I just created an event called `_____` (five underscores) and I was able to search for it using `"_____"`.

(It must be quoted to work - unquoted doesn't work.)

Comment: Well ironically, I used = because I'd thought that would be easy to search (and it's easy to type without have to Shift). Btw the `"====="` isn't working for me..

Comment: I didn't say `"====="` would work. It doesn't, and can't, because Google strips the `=` character from your search. Underscore is a special case - it's considered a "word character" by certain definitions, and so when Google's code removes all non-word characters from the search, it gets left behind and still works. I doubt there will be any other non-alphanumeric that act the same, so if not using shift is important for you then use `xxxxx` or `iiiii` or whatever.

Comment: Also, pressing shift is _not_ difficult. Use your little finger (or your left hand) when your right middle finger goes for the `-`/`_` key.

Comment: of course I could use that for the future but not the current ones you see.

Comment: Well depending on what other events you have, select "show search options" and in the "Doesn't have" field enter something like: `This OR That OR Birthday OR Christmas OR Elephants`

This shows all events recent/coming events, excluding ones with the specified keywords - which (with enough words used) will eventually leave the ===== ones behind.